# Dropdown not show selected value only in mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a `select` `menu` with different `options`. I want to select  its `option` dynamically on the basis of current time.
for that i am using following code

```
var currentdate = new Date();
var h = currentdate.getHours();
var m = currentdate.getMinutes();
if(m >= 1 && m <= 15)
{
    m = '00';
}
else if(m >= 16 && m <=44)
{
    m = '30';
}
else if (m >= 45)
{
    h++;
    m = '00';
}
if(h < 12)
{
    var time = h+":"+m+" AM";
    $("#kill-time option").each(function() {
        if($(this).text() === time) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }                   
    });
    $('#kill-time').selectmenu('refresh',true);
}
else
{
    h = h - 12;
    if(h < 10)h="0"+h;
    var time = h+":"+m+" PM";
    $("#kill-time option").each(function() {
        if($(this).text() === time) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }                   
    });
    $('#kill-time').selectmenu('refresh',true);
}
```

It updates the value and also display correct value (in Desktop Browsers) and in mobile browser it it displays like this

[image]

I created [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8bSs/4/) also and check in mobile browser and it have same issue

(I want to change on the basis of `text` not by using `values`)

Comment: A side-note, use `.prop()` like `$(this).prop('selected', true);`

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the question. When I click [GetTime] it shows me the time 11:30 (It's 11:40 here). Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: In computer/laptop browser it works fine and show time correctly (11:40 means it will show 11:30 its correct) its not working only when  i want to run in mobile browsers @DeanMeehan

Answer (score 1):

Think I got it sorted. I changed two things on your code. One the HTML for the times around 12 where wrote as pM instead of PM.

Also your JS converts time from 24 hour at 12 to 0, when in fact we say 12:00 for Noon and then 1:00 for 1PM so i've simply added another condition.

```
if(h!==12){
    h = h - 12;
}
```

I have tested this using Google Dev Tools Emulation on Google Nexus S, iPhone 5 and Windows Phone and seems to be working fine.

---

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument,
>   defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with
>   the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were
>   retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope
>   of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only
>   properties.

You will then have to change any attr() referring to any of the above elements and change them to

$(this).prop('selected',true);

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfGVz/)**

Comment: +1 for this condition `if(h!==12){`.  But still now working if i run on mobile device. (testing on Samsung S3). It will show like i posted in question (picture)

Comment: and if I change `attr` to `prop` (as @Satpal tell in his first comment ) than it also work fine on mobile devices. (i don't know why but it works in that case)

Comment: yea if i use `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: Updated my Answer to reflect for future reference.